# Add wait for messages

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have this Angular code used to display notifications after login:

```
<div id="toast-container" class="toast-top-right toast-container">
   <div toast-component="" class="toast-success ngx-toastr ng-trigger ng-trigger-flyInOut ng-animating" style="">
      <!----><button aria-label="Close" class="toast-close-button ng-tns-c15-20 ng-star-inserted" style=""><span class="ng-tns-c15-20" aria-hidden="true">×</span></button><!----><!----><!---->
      <div aria-live="polite" role="alertdialog" class="toast-message ng-star-inserted" aria-label="Default warehouse retrieved." style=""> Default warehouse retrieved. </div>
      <!---->
   </div>
   <div toast-component="" class="toast-success ngx-toastr ng-trigger ng-trigger-flyInOut" style="opacity: 1;">
      <!----><button aria-label="Close" class="toast-close-button ng-tns-c15-19 ng-star-inserted" style=""><span class="ng-tns-c15-19" aria-hidden="true">×</span></button><!----><!----><!---->
      <div aria-live="polite" role="alertdialog" class="toast-message ng-star-inserted" aria-label="User is authorized to run the FootPrint Mobile Web application." style=""> User is authorized to run the FootPrint Mobile Web application. </div>
      <!---->
   </div>
   <div toast-component="" class="toast-success ngx-toastr ng-trigger ng-trigger-flyInOut" style="opacity: 1;">
      <!----><button aria-label="Close" class="toast-close-button ng-tns-c15-18 ng-star-inserted" style=""><span class="ng-tns-c15-18" aria-hidden="true">×</span></button><!----><!----><!---->
      <div aria-live="polite" role="alertdialog" class="toast-message ng-star-inserted" aria-label="User session info saved successfully." style=""> User session info saved successfully. </div>
      <!---->
   </div>
   <div toast-component="" class="toast-success ngx-toastr ng-trigger ng-trigger-flyInOut" style="opacity: 1;">
      <!----><button aria-label="Close" class="toast-close-button ng-tns-c15-17 ng-star-inserted" style=""><span class="ng-tns-c15-17" aria-hidden="true">×</span></button><!----><!----><!---->
      <div aria-live="polite" role="alertdialog" class="toast-message ng-star-inserted" aria-label="Login successful." style=""> Login successful. </div>
      <!---->
   </div>
</div>
```

I use this Selenium code to get the text from notifications which are displayed one by one with 1-2 seconds delay:

```
            WebDriverWait failedLoginWebDriverWait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 7);
    
            WebElement failedLoginWebElement = failedLoginWebDriverWait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[@id='toast-container']")));
    
    
    WebElement element2d = failedLoginWebElement.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@aria-label='Login successful.']"));

    System.out.println("!!!!!!!!!!! " + element2d.getText());

    WebElement element3d = failedLoginWebElement.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@aria-label='Default warehouse retrieved.']"));

    System.out.println("!!!!!!!!!!! " + element3d.getText());

    WebElement element4d = failedLoginWebElement.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@aria-label='Authorized warehousees retrieved.']"));

    System.out.println("!!!!!!!!!!! " + element4d.getText());

    WebElement element5d = failedLoginWebElement.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@aria-label='User is authorized to run the FootPrint Mobile Web application.']"));

    System.out.println("!!!!!!!!!!! " + element5d.getText());


protected void waitUntilElementNotDisplayed(final WebElement webElement, WebDriver driver) {
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 5);
        ExpectedCondition elementIsDisplayed = new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {
            public Boolean apply(WebDriver arg0) {
                try {
                    webElement.isDisplayed();
                    System.out.println(webElement.getText());
                    return false;
                }
                catch (NoSuchElementException e ) {
                    return true;
                }
                catch (StaleElementReferenceException f) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        };
        wait.until(elementIsDisplayed);
    }
```

I get the value from the first message 'Login successful.'. But for the next message I get `org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//div[@aria-label='Default warehouse retrieved.']"}`.

Looks like I need to add some sleep or listener messages to appear. Is there some solution?

Comment: Can you share `<div id="toast-container" class="toast-top-right toast-container">` bit more HTML above this tag from HTML structure ? I want to make sure that it is not in iframe.

Comment: System.out.println("!!!!!!!!!!! " + element3d.getText()); Are you getting exception at this line ?

Comment: I get `Unable to locate element`

Comment: I know that. Can you answer above two questions ?

Comment: Here is the page code: https://pastebin.com/Dx4KACeS

Comment: I get the exception here: `WebElement element3d = failedLoginWebElement.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@aria-label='Default warehouse retrieved.']"));` for `findElement`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `iframe` involved, Probably you would need to introduced `WebDriverWait` to resolve this issue.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20); 
WebElement element3d = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[@aria-label='Default warehouse retrieved.']")));
System.out.println("!!!!!!!!!!! " + element3d.getText());
```

Learn more about Explicit wait here [official docs](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/webdriver/waits/#explicit-wait)

Comment: In general it's working but I get very strange issue: From time to time for example I get this error: `org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for visibility of element located by By.xpath: //div[@aria-label='User session info saved successfully.'] (tried for 20 second(s) with 500 milliseconds interval)`

Comment: I also get `org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document` What could be the problem here?

Comment: @PeterPenzov : Stale element issue one would probably get cause they have moved to a new page and trying to access elements of previous page, Selenium can't access them anymore when you are in new page. So it throws `StaleElementReferenceException`

Comment: is there some solution?

Comment: @PeterPenzov : There are ways.. Can I have the URL ?

Comment: It's a internal system behind VPN.